# plotting stock data in plot.ly

Tags: python, plotly, candlestick-chart

I am trying to plot candlestick and simple moving average data using plot.ly
as you see in the chart, there is empty value line plotted where there is no date/price data available actually. the data for this chart is also shown.

So in chart, you can see that the non-trading hours are also plotted. How to avoid this?

[image: stock chart]

[image: stock data in pandas dataframe]

Comment: Please show data and code as text, not image. The graph is fine

Comment: i was not able to properly post the dataframe output data. it was not readable. so posted an image of the table. i will keep this in mind. thanks

Comment: You posted a picture of console output. Copy it and format it as code. If I want to create a test on my machine, I can't copy the image.

Answer (score 0):

Plotly doesn't seem to support just hidding gaps with no data, as you can see from this [discussion in the plotly community](https://community.plot.ly/t/skip-x-axis-values-for-which-there-are-no-price-y-values/2563/3)

The answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678365/how-can-i-hide-data-gaps-in-plotly) removes the gap by entering explicit null values for every index where the data is empty.

Comment: in my case the input data is from historical candle data and unfortunately i can not add null values or modify the input data in any way. as a work around to insert null values, i will have to first capture the historical candle data into a csv and add null values and then read that csv back into dataframes before plotting.

Comment: @Shivaprashanth. That doesn't make sense. Dataframes are writable. If yours isn't, make a copy that it. Do the operation in memory.

Comment: i guess thats what i have to do. will try that. Thanks @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code that helped me

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(
x=dataset_5.index,
open=dataset_5['open'], 
high=dataset_5['high'],
low=dataset_5['low'], 
close=dataset_5['close'])])
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=True,
    rangebreaks=[
        # NOTE: Below values are bound (not single values), ie. hide x to y
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]),  # hide weekends, eg. hide sat to before mon
        dict(bounds=[18, 9.0], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours outside of 9.30am-4pm
        # dict(values=["2019-12-25", "2020-12-24"])  # hide holidays (Christmas and 
        New Year's, etc)
     ]
  )
  fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
  fig.show()
```